# Donor set recurring start date on a Drupal Webform Contribution Integration

Tags: webform-civicrm, recurring-contributions, iats

Drupal 7.67
Civi 5.13.4
iATSPayments

I have a webform for our contribution page. I just realized that with a civi Contribution Page I can allow donors to set the start date for their recurring donation. But that does not seem to be an option in the Webform settings.

Can I create a form component that uses the proper key to allow me to set this up in my webform?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is:

*No*.

Unfortunately Webform CiviCRM integration does not currently support selecting the start date for a recurring contribution.

The longer answer is that it would not be impossible nor incredibly complex to add this field as a supported option for the CiviCRM integration to allow you to expose this option via Webform & CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

On a CiviCRM Contribution page - the select Future start date of a Recurring Contribution is added by our iATS Payments Extension (Configuration for it lives on the iATS Settings page).

Because it’s payment processor specific (it requires ability to tokenize a card) I’ve not created a field for it in Webform CiviCRM module.

Having said that - here’s what you can do:
1. configure your webform such that you end up creating a $1 recurring series.
2. on your webform collect the preferred date and amount.
3. manually edit the recurring series to transact on the donor’s prefered date (next scheduled contribution date) and set the amount.

Comment: Creative thinking but I use line items so updating the amount does not work. It does change the amount of the recurring contribution to the new amount. However, it does not update the line item table so all future contributes would still record as $1 on the line item table.